# jquery datatables is not loading table data

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

### Problem:

I am trying to represent data in a tabular format,this data is to be retrieved  from a database My table data is not getting loaded even after  I hard code  values.

### Case:

I am retrieving data from a database and just displaying the data on a UI using Jquery datatables.
  1.I have created a Java-bean for retrieving the data
  2.Created a servlet to retrieve data from a database
  3.I have created a jsp page to display the output

The code is as follows:

```
BuyerViewServlet.java
```

@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    processRequest(request, response);

    processRequest(request, response);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    BuyerView buyerview = getBuyerInfo();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    String json = gson.toJson(buyerview);

    response.setContentType("application/json");

    out.print(json);
    System.out.print(json.trim());

    out.close();

}

   //sets the JavaBean
   public BuyerView getBuyerInfo() {

    BuyerView info = new BuyerView();

    //info.setConsID(45);
    info.setEmailUser("james@kngs.com");

    return info;

  }//END OF getInfo()


///jsp
<table id="consumer_information" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>

        <th>Name of Customer</th>
        <th>Email</th>


    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>          
 </tbody>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1  /js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#consumer_information').dataTable( {
           "sServerMethod ":"POST" ,
         "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing" : false,
            "bServerSide" : false,
            "sAjaxSource" : "./BuyerViewE",
            "bJQueryUI" : true,
            "aoColumns" : [
        { "mData": "Name of Company" },
        { "mData": "Email" }

    ]
   } ); 
     } );


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described exactly what type of error, if any, you are currently getting. However, just looking at your code, it seems that the `src` attribute for one of your `script` tags is incorrect.

You have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1  /js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Try removing the space between '1.10.1' and the '/js'. So basically, change your script tag to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

See if this change fixes your problem. If there are other issues then please provide the specific results/errors you are seeing.

Comment: Ohh yeah, Sorry, this is the error, http://datatables.net/tn/1, which should tranlate to bad JSON format, Ive checked the logger and the JSON format is as follows,

Comment: {"name":"samwel","email":"king@samo.com"}

Comment: @cliffjosiah I don't see anything wrong with the JSON you provided. Did you try making the change I suggested?

Comment: Yes I did, but there was no change, what I am trying to do now is to use JSP instead of ajax to retrieve the data